# How to set multiple select with @shoutem/ui DropDownMenu?

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I use `DropDownMenu` and take a reference from official doumcn https://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/components/dropdown-menu

I want to set two `DropDownMenu` the first is for zone and the second is for city, if user select the zone like East the second `DropDownMenu` should set the value E1、E2

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { DropDownMenu, Text } from '@shoutem/ui';

class TestConfirm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          zone: [
            {
              id: 0,
              brand: "North",
              models:
                {
                  model: "Audi R8",
                  image: {
                    url: "https://shoutem.github.io/img/ui-toolkit/dropdownmenu/Audi-R8.jpg"
                  },
                  description: "North Description"
                },
                children: [{
                    name: "N1",
                    id: 10,
                  },{
                    name: "N2",
                    id: 17,
                  }]
              },
            {
              id: 1,
              brand: "West",
              models: {
                model: "Chiron",
                image: {
                  url: "https://shoutem.github.io/img/ui-toolkit/dropdownmenu/Chiron.jpg"
                },
                description: "West Description"
              },
              children: [{
                name: "W1",
                id: 10,
              },{
                name: "W2",
                id: 17,
              }]
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              brand: "East",
              models: {
                model: "Dodge Viper",
                image: {
                  url: "https://shoutem.github.io/img/ui-toolkit/dropdownmenu/Dodge-Viper.jpg"
                },
                description: "East Description"
              },
              children: [{
                name: "E1",
                id: 10,
              },{
                name: "E2",
                id: 17,
              }]
            },
          ],
        }
      }

  render() {
    const selectedZone = this.state.selectedZone || this.state.zone[0];
    console.log('selectedZone =>');
    console.log(selectedZone);
    console.log('selectedZone.children =>');
    console.log(selectedZone.children);
    return (
      <Screen>
        <DropDownMenu
            styleName="horizontal"
            options={this.state.zone}
            selectedOption={selectedZone ? selectedZone : this.state.zone[0]}
            onOptionSelected={(zone) => this.setState({ selectedZone: zone })}
            titleProperty="brand"
            valueProperty="cars.model"
        />
        <Text styleName="md-gutter-horizontal">
            {selectedZone ?
            selectedZone.models.description :
            this.state.zone[0].models.description}
        </Text>

       <DropDownMenu
            styleName="horizontal"
            options={selectedZone.children}
            selectedOption={selectedZone ? selectedZone : this.state.zone[0].children}
            onOptionSelected={(city) => this.setState({ selectedZone: city })}
            titleProperty="name"
            valueProperty="cars.model"
        />
      </Screen>
    );
  }
}

export default TestConfirm;
```

Here is my screen look like this:
[image]

If i select East it will show error

```
Invalid `selectedOption` {"id":2,"brand":"East","models":{"model":"Dodge Viper","image":{"url":"https://shoutem.github.io/img/ui-toolkit/dropdownmenu/Dodge-Viper.jpg"},"description":"East Description"},"children":[{"name":"E1","id":10},{"name":"E2","id":17}]}, DropDownMenu `selectedOption` must be a member of `options`.Check that you are using the same reference in both `options` and `selectedOption`.
```

I check my console.log will look like this:
[image]

The key `children` under the name is what i want to put it into my second `DropDownMenu`

I have no idea how to do next step. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this.state.zone[0].children` is an array. try using `this.state.zone[0].children[0]`

Comment: Looks like it will be corrected. But i try it and it still shows the same error :(

Comment: Thank you @bennygenel . I fix it like this `selectedOption={selectedZone ? selectedZone.children[0] : this.state.zone[0].children[0]}`  Its working now. Can you post it and i will take the answer.

Comment: is there a way to show image and text in dropdown list?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, all i put the data into DropDownMenu is String array, I suggest you can ask it on official github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedOption` property for the `DropDownMenu` component expects a single object but `this.state.zone[0].children` is an array. You can change it to `this.state.zone[0].children[0]` to fixed the problem.

Also when you change the city dropdown you are updating the zone value in state. This will cause a bug. Try fixing it with setting a different value in state and checking that value for the city dropdown

**Sample**

```
render() {
    const { zone, selectedZone, selectedCity } = this.state
    return (
      <Screen>
        <DropDownMenu
            styleName="horizontal"
            options={zone}
            selectedOption={selectedZone || zone[0]}
            onOptionSelected={(zone) => 
              this.setState({ selectedZone: zone, selectedCity: zone.children[0] } )
            }
            titleProperty="brand"
            valueProperty="cars.model"
        />
        <Text styleName="md-gutter-horizontal">
            {selectedZone ?
            selectedZone.models.description :
            this.state.zone[0].models.description}
        </Text>
       <DropDownMenu
            styleName="horizontal"
            options={selectedZone ? selectedZone.children : zone[0].children } // check if zone selected or set the defaul zone children
            selectedOption={selectedCity || zone[0].children[0] } // set the selected city or default zone city children
            onOptionSelected={(city) => this.setState({ selectedCity: city })} // set the city on change
            titleProperty="name"
            valueProperty="cars.model"
        />
      </Screen>
    );
  }
```

Comment: There is no way to set the second `DropDownMenu` state. looks like i should create another state object.  :(

Comment: @徐博俊 what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean for example the East has the children E1 and E2, if select E2 what ever i use `this.setState` the East still has the children E1 and E2. How the second `DropDownMenu` knows he should set the value for E1 or E2 ?

Comment: @徐博俊 updated question with a sample code. hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. Try your code, show error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`. It looks like there is no selectedZone.children, should i restructure my state object ?

Comment: Sorry i forgot remove `console.log` .The error is gone now.  I try it again find that still has another issue is if i select West or East the second `DropDownMenu` value is gone. Show the error `Invalid `selectedOption` {"name":"N1","id":10}, DropDownMenu selectedOption must be a member of  options.Check that you are using the same reference in both options and  selectedOption` Any idea ?  Thank you again.

Comment: @徐博俊 I missed something and fixed the sample. You need to set the city for a default value when the zone changed. Check the sample code now for the change.

Comment: It is really helps me a lot. I don't even think i can use set state like this. Its working now. Thank you very much @bennygenel